Migrating Work Items from TFS 2012 to Azure DevOps Server 2020
I need to migrate both source and backlog data (Work Items) from TFS 2012 to Azure DevOps Server 2020. Initially, I planned to export the Work Items as a CSV file and manually import them into the new Azure DevOps Server. However, I couldn’t find an option to export Work Items as a CSV (or any other format) in TFS 2012, a feature available in some newer TFS versions.
Does anyone know of a tool or method to export Work Items from TFS 2012? Alternatively, are there any official or third-party resources that explain how to handle this migration?
So far, I’ve come across the witadmin CLI tool, but it seems to only export Work Item definitions as XML, not the actual instances of Work Items.
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!
So far, I’ve come across the witadmin CLI tool, but it seems to only export Work Item definitions as XML, not the actual instances of Work Items.

I am afraid there isn't much good solution for TFS 2012. It is very convenient to use Migration Tools for Azure DevOps to migrate work items. However, for work Item migration, this extension supports all versions of TFS 2013+. You may consider upgrade your server.

First of all, is there a reason you can't just upgrade the TFS 2012 server to a more recent version? Or, a 2nd option, attach a copy of the collection database  to an already existing Azure DevOps server? That would trigger an automatic update process.
If those 2 options aren't what you're after, your best bet is to leverage the Azure DevOps Work Item Migration Tools. With that you can do a full fidelity migration from any TFS or Azure DevOps Server to another.

Main reason I wanted to avoid upgrading TFS 2012 is because as soon as migration is over that server will be put out of use because of that it seemed like to much effort to upgrade server that will be deleted.
That path with collection database is a bit to risky for my case because Azure DevOps server is under heavy use so any problem with that server is really bad. Because of that I look for option to just export import WI without data tier manipulation.
But most likely option is that TFS 2012 need to be updated to TFS 2015, because tool that you suggested requires TFS2013+
Thanks for help
